# Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I install pgadmin4 using the following command **sudo install pgadmin4** and then I installed postgresql using **sudo install postgresql**  . In my terminal I ran the command **psql -U postgres -h localhost**
It shows [connection refuse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lYTz.png)

Then I go to pgadmin4 and created a server and I wanted to connect to the server it shows
[pgadmin connection refuse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfKuG.png)

Then I wrote **host     all             all             all                     md5** in *pg_hba.conf* file and I wrote **listen_addresses = '*'** to *postgresql.conf* file. and I wrote the following command **sudo service postgresql restart**  but again It shows connection refuse message. 
I wrote **psql**  and it shows [connections on Unix domain socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWFyc.png)
Can you please help me in this regard? What I have missed?

Comment: This question should be better asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you add your pg_hba.conf to the question?

Comment: If the server was already running, you would need "restart" instead of "start"

Comment: I did it but same issue

Comment: Did the restart actually work?  Is postgres running?

Comment: Can you run `sudo service postgresql status` and share the output?

Comment: It  is running and in active mode

Comment: "sudo install pgadmin4"  What is "install"?

Comment: can you pls explain your question?